# Rich text box Color.Red does not exist

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox

I have  `Rich` Textbox and it's named `textBox1`

When I try this:

```
                    textBox1.AppendText(value);
                    textBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

the `Red` is underlined and errored:

`Error  2   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Red' and no extension method 'Red' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Form1.cs    73  57`

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct namespace for Color object.

Comment: Does your form have a field or property named `Color`? If so, you need to disambiguate it by specifying `System.Drawing.Color.Red` instead.

Comment: @Michael Liu, post it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your form have a field or property named `Color` whose type is `string`? If it does, then the "Color" in `Color.Red` refers to that field or property instead of the `System.Drawing.Color` type.

You can disambiguate the reference by specifying the `System.Drawing` namespace:

```
textBox1.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```